# from a succession of environments to a table

Tags: tables, environments

I have three environments `A`, `B` and `C`, in my document `A` is always followed by `B`. `A` and `B` are always contained in `C`.

For example :

```
\begin{C}
 \begin{A}
  blabla
 \end{A}
 \begin{B}
  blabla
 \end{B}
\end{C}
```

Is it possible to redefine theses environments to make a table.

I tried something like

```
\newenvironment{C}{\begin{tabular}{cc}}{\end{tabular}{cc}}
\newenvironment{A}{}{&}
\newenvironment{B}{}{\\}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the grouping is causing the problem. Since you're only interested in adjusting the way `\end{<env>}` functions, [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) `\AfterEndEnvironment{<env>}` can help here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newenvironment{C}{\begin{tabular}{cc}}{\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{A}{}{}
\AfterEndEnvironment{A}{&}
\newenvironment{B}{}{}
\AfterEndEnvironment{B}{\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{C}
  \begin{A} 1 blabla A \end{A}
  \begin{B} 2 blabla B \end{B}
  \begin{A} 3 blabla A \end{A}
  \begin{B} 4 blabla B \end{B}
  \begin{A} 5 blabla A \end{A}
  \begin{B} 6 blabla B \end{B}
\end{C}

\end{document}
```